# Feedback generator for text in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

I am looking to make a program that reads a document and gives us feedback on how to improve it for example an essay. So far I have split the essay into its main components like introduction, development paragraph, and conclusion. How would I be able to make a program that can give feedback on each paragraph so that the user would be able to improve it? Is this type of program even possible or is the technology not advances enough. Would machine learning be the best technique. The code so far is not much but here it is:

```
import nltk

def parse_essay(essay_filename):
    with open(essay_filename, 'r') as file:
        paragraphs = [x.strip('\n') for x in file.readlines() if x != '\n' and x != '\t\n']
        return paragraphs[0], paragraphs[1], paragraphs[2], paragraphs[3]

def get_introduction_feedback(text):
    sentences = nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize(text)
    hook = ' '.join(sentences[:3])
    thesis = sentences[3]
    arguments = ' '.join(sentences[4:])

def get_development_feedback(text):
    pass

def get_conclusion_feedback(text):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ESSAY = 'essay.txt'

    intro, dev1, dev2, conclusion = parse_essay(ESSAY)
    intro_feedback = get_introduction_feedback(intro)
    dev1_feedback = get_development_feedback(dev1)
    dev2_feedback = get_development_feedback(dev2)
    conclusion_feedback = get_conclusion_feedback(conclusion)

    print('Introduction:\n\n{}\n\nDevelopment 1:\n\n{}\n\nDevelopment 2:\n\n{}\n\nConclusion:\n\n{}'.format(intro_feedback, dev1_feedback, dev2_feedback, conclusion_feedback))
```

Also the essay document that it uses is a 4 paragraph essay, where paragraph 1 is the intro, paragraph 2 and 3 are development and 4 is the conclusion.

Comment: You can't really do this without machine learning.

Comment: If you know nothing of machine learning this is a great first step. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKxRvEZd3Mw&list=PLpH1NIoV8S8cxpmPlxVRr-RvnR2MBZ5gY

Comment: I know about machine learning however im not quite sure how to implement it here. What kind of algorithm should be used? @EmettSpeer

Comment: That I don't know. I'm still just getting started with machine learning and have not gotten that far yet. It is something I'm interested in though.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a very hard problem to tackle with plain Machine Learning. The essays would be very domain specific and you would require a very extensive (and labeled) essays database.

An Unsupervied approach may be useful, like Word-embedding via Artificial neural networks.

The first thing that you should think is "What problem I am trying to solve?" or "What question am I trying to anwer?" Once you have that, then you can define an objective function to optimize using ML, or you alredy found another paradigm to use while trying to answer those questions.

Comment: What would be the structure of a complex algorithm like this? Do any open source versions of this exist? @GermainL

Comment: You would need to transform the input text into a binary vector using a "Bag-of-words"

The binary vector is just a bunch of 1s and 0s representing  the question "Is a given word in the Essay?"

You then use the binary vector to "predict" or "rank" how good is the Essay... and that is the tricky question, How can you tell programmaticaly if an Essay is good or not?

This would be the simplest approach since you wouldn't be taking into account the order or the words.

Maybe you should stick to a Rule-based approach. Like, if certain words are mentioned in a certain order, then its good,